# Como fazer uma rotina em C ficar executando e não pare até eu executar um comando?

Tags: c

Boa Noite, gostaria de fazer uma rotina em C tipo assim:
Digamos que eu tenha um loop que fica imprimindo a letra 'a' e enquanto eu não digitar nada ele continua imprimindo, porém no momento em que eu apertar 'c' por exemplo, ele comece a imprimir a letra 'c' e fique imprimindo enquanto eu não digitar nada. É mais ou menos isso que eu gostaria mas não estou conseguindo reproduzir isso. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar o `kbhit`:

```
do
{
  puts("c");
} while(!kbhit());
```

O único problema, é que não funciona em todos os compiladores.

> exemplos de uso em outros compiladores: [exemplos](https://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/63166-kbhit-linux.html)